# jQuery UI Dialog - content from iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I know a lot of variation of this question are available but none of them is working for what I have.

Currently I have div exposed on a page and I use following jQuery code create a dialog box control and style it:

```
            hoverApplet = $("#s_" + actAppletPH + "_div");  
            hoverApplet.hide();
            hoverApplet.dialog({ height: 'auto',
                        width: 'auto',
                        modal: true,
                        autoOpen:false,
                        title:'Hello World',
                        overlay: { opacity: 0.5, background: 'black'}
            }).dialog("widget")
            .find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css({
                "float": "right",
                border: 0,
                padding: 0
            })
            .find(".ui-dialog-title").css({
                display: "none"
            }).end()
            .find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").css({
                top: 0,
                right: 0,
                margin: 0,
                "z-index": 999
            });
```

Then I use following code to open this dialog on button click.

```
hoverApplet.dialog("open").dialog('option', 'position',[event.clientX,event.clientY]);
```

Now this below URL is suppose to give me same DIV at run time

```
http://localhost:8080/start.swe?SWECmd=GetApplet&SWEApplet=Activity+Form+Applet+-+SA&IsPortlet=1&SWESM=Edit&KeepAlive=1
```

I need to show the same dialog now that should get its content from iframe where source is above mentioned URL.

I don't know what change should I make to work properly.

Thanks

Comment: I don't get the question, do you want to have an IFRAME in a jquery ui dialog? Or do you wanna call an iframe, get the contents and create a ui dialog without the iframe?

Comment: I want to have iframe in the jQuery dialog.

Comment: Whats difficult about it? Just wrap a div around, select it with jquery and call .dialog()